# помогите написать программу на java

Tags: java

Напишите программу, которая в последовательности натуральных чисел определяет максимальное число, кратное 5.  Программа должна вывести одно число — максимальное число, кратное 5.
Я написал,но почему-то не работает.
Я хочу чтобы было с бесконечным циклом вайл и сканнером

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class OGE4{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int max = 1;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true){
             int num = scanner.nextInt();
            if (num > max && num % 5 == 0) {
                max = num;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты пытаешься бесконечно читать, конечно выход должен был быть предусмотрен в IDE комбинацией аля Ctrl+Z из обычной консоли(гуглить надо), но можно предусмотреть это и программно ->

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class OGE4{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int max = 1;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(**scanner.hashNextInt**){
             int num = scanner.nextInt();
            if (num > max && num % 5 == 0) {
                max = num;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

Тут всё  как у тебя за исключением того, что ввод происходит до ввода неInt, что и означает выделенная функция **scanner.hashNextInt**
 Теперь вводи пока не надоесть, а затем введи любой символ(*не число*)

*hashNextInt **только** просматривает число, а вот **nextInt** уже забирает*

Answer (score 3):

Ввод натуральных чисел происходит вне цикла и записывается в отдельный массив. Цикл пробегает по каждому элементу массива и проверяет на кратность 5.

```
        int max = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > max && array[i] % 5 == 0) {
                max = array[i];  

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Ваша ошибка состоит в том, что вы никогда не выходите из цикл `while`. Ваша `idea` должна это подчеркивать. Решение данной проблемы можно решить несколькими способами (учитывая желание `while`):
1. Этот способ на мой взгляд самый простой. Использовать стоп число, например, -1.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class OGE4{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int max = 1;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int stop = 0;
        while(stop != -1){
            int num = scanner.nextInt();
            stop = num;
            if(num == -1) {return;};
            if (num > max && num % 5 == 0) {
                max = num;
            }

        }
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

2.Окончание не числом:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class OGE4{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int max = -100000;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true){
            String string = scanner.next();
            try {
                int num = Integer.parseInt(string);
                if (num > max && num % 5 == 0) {
                    max = num;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(max);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```